C memory access Error Segmentation Fault -
uint32_t binDataSize = 0;  
void  *binData =Snapshot_Recovery(argc, argv, &binDataSize);

snapshot_header *snapPtr = (snapshot_header *)malloc(binDataSize);
printf("bindataSize is %u\n", binDataSize);
printf("Size of binData: %zu bytes\n", binData);

snapPtr = (snapshot_header *)binData;
printf("Transaction Code: %d\n", snapPtr->trans_code);

While running this or the below gives segmentation fault core dumped error
uint32_t binDataSize = 0;
        void  *binData =Snapshot_Recovery(argc, argv, &binDataSize);

        snapshot_header *snapPtr = (snapshot_header *)binData;
        printf("bindataSize is %u\n", binDataSize);
        printf("Size of binData: %zu bytes\n", binData);

        if(snapPtr != NULL){
                 printf("Transaction Code: %d\n", snapPtr->trans_code);
        }else{
                printf("snapPtr is NULL");
        }

gives segmentation fault
bindataSize is 10747006
Size of binData: 1763438762 bytes
Segmentation fault (core dumped)


I know segmentation fault occurs due to inappropriate memory usage, but I couldn't find out where am I going wrong
typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) {
        int16_t trans_code;
        int32_t size;
        int32_t no_of_records;
        int32_t lsn;
        int16_t stream_id;
}snapshot_header;


I am printing the binDataSize & binData in order to match with the actual values of it, & it matched.
I tried matching the original values with the returned values of the Snapshot_Recovery & the values
matched everytime. I tried with memcpy(snapPtr, binData, binDataSize) but this is also giving the same error

What is the value of snapPtr? This would happen if it's a null pointer.

You have a memory leak, BTW. You reassign snapPtr without freeing the old value.

binData is not a size_t, you shouldn't print it with %zu format.

@Barmar this is not NULL at any point of time since the binData gets populated by a callback function. Even if we add a NULL checker still the error persists.
Even if I do it like this --
snapshot_header *snapPtr = (snapshot_header *)binData
it gives segmentation Fault
Yes if I print it using %u for binDataSize this prints the data

Why do you malloc snapPtr when you ultimately just throw it away and assign binData to it? Also, did you make sure to check if snapPtr is not NULL after the line: snapPtr = (snapshot_header *)binData;?

There's so much wrong with these code snippets already. You're not really checking anything for errors. You haven't shown what the Snapshot_Recovery function does, despite the pointer it returns being potentially the root of all your problems. You leak memory. You regularly use incorrect printf format specifiers. The "Size of binData" diagnostic is comlpetely bogus. You rely on type punning which violates strict aliasing. You provide two different versions of your code without explanation. You should run the program in gdb to identify which line it crashes on.

snapPtr doesn't have to be NULL to be invalid; are we sure Snapshot_Recovery is returning good data?  paddy's right, you need to run this code through a debugger (after fixing the other problems people have identified).

You're using the wrong format specifier (%zu) for a null pointer. This can lead to undefined behavior.
Instead, use (%p):
printf("binData pointer: %p\n", (void *)binData);


This is unlikely the reason for the segmentation fault, which occurs only after the printf.

Based on your output this line appears to be the issue:
printf("Transaction Code: %d\n", snapPtr->trans_code);

meaning snapPtr isn't a good pointer value.  A pointer value doesn't have to be NULL to be invalid.  The problem appears to be that your Snapshot_Recovery function is returning bad data; you will want to step  through it with a debugger to make sure something important isn't getting stepped on.  If the pointer's bad, then it's likely binDataSize isn't being assigned correctly either.

Some general issues:
printf("Size of binData: %zu bytes\n", binData);

It seems like you meant to write
printf("Size if binData: %zu bytes\n", sizeof binData );

but this will only give you the size of the pointer object itself (4 or 8 depending on your platform), not the size of the entire snapshot.  sizeof *binData won't work either because that's equivalent to sizeof (void), which is a constraint violation and will trigger a diagnostic.  You can't query the size of the snapshot through a pointer; that's what binDataSize is for.
Similarly, sizeof snapPtr gives you the size of the pointer object, not what it points to.  sizeof *snapPtr gives you the size of the snapshot header, but not the entire snapshot.
If you want to look at the pointer value itself, use %p:
printf("binData = %p\n", binData); 
printf("snapPtr = %p\n", (void *) snapPtr);

You do not need to explicitly cast binData to type snapshot_header * in the assignment; C allows implicit conversions between void * and other pointer types, so you can just write:
snapPtr = binData;

Less eye-stabby, less potential for mayhem.
Make sure you use the right conversion specifiers for the right types; for example, if binDataSize is uint32_t, then you'd use the %PRIu32 format specifier:
#include <stdint.h>
...
printf( "binDataSize = %" PRIu32 "\n", binDataSize );

Similarly, you should use PRId16 for the trans_code member:
printf( "Transaction code: %" PRId16 "\n", snapPtr->tran_code );

but figure out why Snapshot_Recovery is returning a bad pointer value first.
